# Fit ggplot exactly to viewport size

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

Suppose I have a ggplot object:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")
p <- qplot(0:10,0:10)
```

And some grid page with a box:

```
grid.newpage()
vp <- viewport(width = unit(210, "mm"), height = unit(297, "mm"))
pushViewport(vp)

# Inner box:
box <- viewport(unit(105,"mm"),unit(150,"mm"),width=unit(150,"mm"),height=unit(150,"mm"))
pushViewport(box)
grid.rect()
```

I can fit the plot inside as follows:

```
# Print ggplot plot:
upViewport()
print(p ,vp = box)
```

But I want to accomplish having the plot inside this page such that the plotting area (not the margins) exactly fill this box, and the legend, axis labels etcetera sort of "spill over" outside the plot. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at the egg package on github

Answer (score 7):

There is possibly an easier way than the following.

This uses `gtable` functions to disassemble the ggplot into the plot panel and the two axes. It then positions the components into viewports so that plot panel exactly fills the inner box, but that the axes are outside the boundary of the inner box. The red boundary lines and the rotation are to demonstrate (mainly to myself) that the axes are outside but move with the inner box.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

p <- qplot(0:10,0:10)

# Convert the plot to a grob
gt <- ggplotGrob(p)

# Extract panel, axes and axis labels
panel = gtable_filter(gt, "panel")
axis_l = gtable_filter(gt, "axis-l")
axis_b = gtable_filter(gt, "axis-b")
xlab = gtable_filter(gt, "xlab-b")
ylab = gtable_filter(gt, "ylab-l")

# Put labels and axes together
left = cbind(ylab, axis_l, size = "first")
bottom = rbind(axis_b, xlab, size = "last")

# Get their width / height
w = convertX(sum(left$width), "mm") 
h = convertX(sum(bottom$height), "mm")

# Outer box
grid.newpage()
outerBox <- viewport(width = unit(125, "mm"), height = unit(150, "mm"))
pushViewport(outerBox)
grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = "red", fill = NA))

# Width and height of inner box (in mm)
width = 60
height = 70

# Inner box
innerBox <- viewport(x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.6, "npc"), 
                width = unit(width, "mm"), height = unit(height, "mm"), angle = -30)

# Viewport for left axis and label
Vleft = viewport(x = unit(0, "npc") - .5*w, y = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
                width = w, height = unit(height, "mm"))

# Viewport for bottom axis and label
Vbottom = viewport(x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0, "npc") - .5*h, 
                width = unit(width, "mm"), height = h)

pushViewport(innerBox)
grid.draw(panel)
grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = "red", fill = NA, lwd = 2))

pushViewport(Vbottom)
grid.draw(bottom)

upViewport()
pushViewport(Vleft)
grid.draw(left)

popViewport()
popViewport()
popViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW pkg egg defines some functions along those lines, to wrap a ggplot into 3x3 gtable where the central cell is the panel